# AS3 Best way to declare variables inside loop

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, for-loop

Is it possible better to declare variables without having to write one by one?
I need 200 but... no way.

My code i have:

```
var var0:Array = new Array();

var var01:Sprite = new Sprite();
var var02:Sprite = new Sprite();
var var03:Sprite = new Sprite();
etc to 200...
```

And inside for loop:

```
for( var i:Number = 0; i < arrayBig.length; i++ ){
    var0[i] = new Sprite();
    ...
}
```

But Why cant I write `var var0[i]:Sprite = new Sprite();` in the statments?

The error is `Error #1086 Syntax error: expecting semicolon before`

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot index independent variables and you cannot concatenate variable names to form names of other variables (well, not the way you attempted).

You need to create an array of `Sprite` objects. An [array](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) is a data structure that stores several things at once. (A one-dimensional array is called a [vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html).)

To store sprites in a vector, you'd write:

```
var sprites:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite> ();

for ( var i:int = 0; i < 200; i++ )
{
    sprites.push ( new Sprite () );
}
```

This loop creates 200 `Sprite` instances and stores all of them in the `sprites` array (really, `Vector`). You can then access individual sprites by simply indexing them:

```
sprites[n]....
```

where `n` goes from 0 to `N-1` if the `Vector` has `N` total elements.

Comment: the execution time is up to 15" and crash :/ Error #1502

Comment: inside a dynamic class you could always have:  this["someName"+i.toString()] = new Sprite(). But this is not OOP. The solution provided by xxbbcc is the correct one. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i will answer for your question.

"But Why cant I write var var0[i]:Sprite = new Sprite(); in the statements?"
we cant override one object with that of the other same object in the class. thats the reason, we are declaring as "var0[i] = new Sprite();". spl case for sprite object in flex.